# Add multiple bytes array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm adding multiple bytes array from each row, that means I need to append all of them to a variable. But this prints a empty byte array because it can't be changed. What I can do to append more bytes?

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
int matchesLength = 0;

try {
      boolean b = rs.last();

      if (b) {
        matchesLength = rs.getRow();
      }
}
catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] matches = new byte[118 * matchesLength];

while ( rs.next() ) {
  String matchId = rs.getString("id");
  String matchTitle = rs.getString("title");
  String matchDescription = rs.getString("description");
  int matchPlayers = rs.getInt("max_players");
  int matchMaxPlayers = rs.getInt("max_players");
  String matchHostId = rs.getString("host_id");

  short matchPlayersShort = (short) matchPlayers;
  byte[] matchPlayersBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(matchPlayersShort).array();

  short matchMaxPlayersShort = (short) matchMaxPlayers;
  byte[] matchMaxPlayersBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(matchMaxPlayersShort).array();

  byte[][] match = {
      String.format("%1$-" + 32 + "s", matchId).getBytes(),
      String.format("%1$-" + 22 + "s", matchTitle).getBytes(),
      String.format("%1$-" + 44 + "s", matchDescription).getBytes(),
      matchPlayersBytes,
      matchMaxPlayersBytes,
      String.format("%1$-" + 16 + "s", matchHostId).getBytes()
  };

  // global offset variable, for each array copy
  combineBytes(match, matches);
}
```

Comment: What does `combineBytes` do?

Comment: @SubOptimal for each all the arrays of "match", then uses array copy to add the array to "matches" and increments the offset. (the offset is a global variable, it doesn't reset to 0)

Comment: Maybe you should use [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). This should give you the possibility to have a "dynamic" bytearray.

Comment: Why you could not assign the resulting array of `combineBytes` to `matches`?

Comment: @SubOptimal Not working as I need to assign it every time row, you sure?

Comment: @Flown Working on it, thanks.

Comment: @Flown Not working after writing, flushing and converting to byte array. I'll double check later anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to create a class for encapsulate each row?

```
public class Match{
  private String matchId;
  private String matchTitle;
  private String matchDescription;
  etc....

  set and get for all variables;

  public byte[] getBytes(){
    here a logic to transform this attributes in a array of bytes
  }
}
```

Then you create a ArrayList matchList that will be filled in the rs.next() loop.

Then you will just need:

```
while(rs.next()){
  match = new Match();
  match.setBlabla(rs.get(value));
  ....all sets
  list.add(match);
}
```

when you send it through socket to your clients you just read the list and do your logic with the bytes.

Lets supose you have a list of 10 rows and you want it as bytes.

```
ArrayList<Match> matchList = new ArrayList<Match>();
Match m;
while(rs.next()){
  m = new Match();
  m.set // one set for each attribute getting the value from rs.get
  matchList.add(m);
}
```

Now for send it:

```
for(Match m : matchList){
  byte[] bytesToSend = m.getBytes(); //you defined this method
  send(bytesTosend) //one match send for time
}
```

IF you want to send all matches togheter, you have to do a loop to calculate the total bytes in the list because each Match in the list will have a diferent size in bytes (description changes, title chantes etc)

Comment: Thanks. I'm kinda lost, can I convert everything to bytes?

Comment: When you say everything you mean only the attributes of Match right? like matchid, matchtitle, matchdescription etc.?

Comment: Yeah, only that. Every attribute has a fixed length.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this ASAP. I'd send all the matches but all the attributes have fixed length so that would be easy.